# How to install other iOS simulators in Xcode 4.1?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, ios-simulator

I am trying to get into iOS development and yesterday I finally made a VMWare virtual machine on Windows with **Mac OS X Lion 10.7.1** because this is the only version that I made it run as a virtual machine and I first want to take a look at all of this before buying a Mac cause I am .NET developer.

So, when trying to update OS with the actual Xcode version, virtual machine crashes. Due to this, the version that can run here for Xcode is the **4.1** *(correct me if wrong)* and I installed successfully too.

Now everything is working fine but when I create a new project on Xcode I looked at the simulators and the only one I can see is the **iOS 4.3 iPhone simulator** *(not sure if the iPad simulator too)*.

So, my question is...

***How can I install other simulators like iOS 5 iPhone or iPad simulators individualy using Xcode 4.1? And If this is not possible and I made an app using what I got, will it run on iOS5 too? or how can I look if it runs good on iPad and iOS5?***

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the simulators under Xcode Preferrences > Downloads > Components.

Comment: I will test this later and let you know :-)